# How to use Split() for making a command system in c#

Tags: c#

I want to do something like this:

```
string a = Console.Readline();
string[] b = a.Split(' ');
string i = b[0];
string j = b[1];
```

Now the problem is, putting the 'string j' may be optional like the input may be `hi hello` here `hello` is optional. How to make the code work if someone doesn't put something in place of hello.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want the the code to do if that happens?

Comment: For some reason SO won't allow me to edit the question but there is a small compile typo in your code  - `Console.Readline` should be `Console.ReadLine`

Answer (score 0):

Since the "commands" entered by the user will be stored in the array (e.g. `b` based on your code) after the `split`, I don't think it's necessary to store them in individual variables yourself. Thus, avoiding the problem you have in your current setup. On the other hand, if you want to see if a specific "command" was keyed in, you can do something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("> ");

        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        // Doing it like this will automatically remove blanks from the resulting array
        // so you won't have to clean it up yourself
        string[] commands = input.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Contains is from the System.Linq namespace
        // this will allow you to see if a given value is in the array
        if (commands.Contains("hi"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("> The command 'hi' has been received.");
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

You can use Linq's `Contains` method to check if a specific value exists in the array of command strings.

if you just want to see all the commands in the array, a simple `for loop` would be enough.

```
        // The Length property of the array will give you the
        // number of items it contains
        for(int i = 0; i < commands.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("> Command read: {0} ", commands[i]);
        }
```

One more thing, I suggest that you normalize the inputs your application will receive as to avoid problems when filtering through them. You could do this by calling the `ToLower` method available to `ReadLine`:

```
      string inputs = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Length` property to check how many elements are in the split array.

If there are not enough elements in the array to assign the optional value you can set it to `null`.

In the rest of your code you just have to null-check the optional value before using it.

Something liket his would work:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine(); 
string[] tokens = input.Split(' ');

string hi = tokens[0];
string optional = tokens.Length > 1 ? tokens[1] : null; // make sure we have enough elements

Console.WriteLine(hi);

// null check before using the optional value
if (optional != null)
    Console.WriteLine(optional);

// or 
Console.WriteLine(optional ?? "Optional value is null..");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing the arrays particular element by its index position, I would use `foreach` loop to iterate over a list like:

```
string a = Console.ReadLine();
string[] b = a.Split(' ');

foreach (string elem in b)
{
   Console.WriteLine(elem); // Do whatever you want with each element
}
Console.ReadLine();
```